# How to display values in thousands in MDX icCube

Tags: mdx, iccube

How to display the value for a measure in thousands.
I would assume to do it as follows:

`FORMAT_STRING="#,,"`

But the data returns: 10000000.001
while I would expect: 10,000

Answer (score 2):

The format follows the format as described in the documentation of [FORMAT_STRING](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/cellProperties/FORMAT_STRING.php) :

```
 FORMAT_STRING="#,###" or  "#,##0" or "#,##0.0"
```

when defining the format you should not use your locale, but use the ',' separator for the thousands and the '.' for the decimal.

Separators will be automatically converted to your locale language in the output.

hope it helps